# Do I roll my Wild Die when rolling to recover from being shaken?

Tags: savage-worlds

In Savage Worlds combat, I find my characters getting in a lot of trouble because they become Shaken. When I roll to get un-Shaken, my GM says, of course, to make a Spirit roll with a TN of 4. However, he never says to roll a Wild Die along with it. Is that correct? Or should I be rolling both my Attribute and my Wild Die?

Basically:
Do I roll my Wild Die when rolling to recover from being shaken?

Answer (score 8):

## Yes

Wild Cards roll the Wild Die for attribute rolls, and rolling Spirit to unshake is an attribute roll. From *Savage Worlds Deluxe*, page 63, “The Wild Die”:

> Wild Cards roll an extra d6 and take the highest of their normal die or the “Wild Die” when making skill or attribute rolls.

Comment: To expand, damage and running are two of the only cases where you *don't* roll a wild die, because they are neither skill nor attribute rolls. Pretty much everything else that a character does falls under one or the other.